# I can't find a list of all apps I've ever purchased ( paid $ free). From my iPhone

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios-appstore, applications

I'm trying to find a certain few apps that I know I purchased but I can't remember the name of. I don't have access to my computer right now & there's an app that I really could use right now but I forgot the name of it so I can't just go to the app store and re-install it simply because I can't find it.

I don't, and won't have access to my computers iTunes for a few days. Otherwise I could just plug in my iPhone to my PC boot up iTunes and go through my list of thousands of apps that I've purchased and sync it to my iPhone. So if anyone knows ho I can get a list from my iPhone of every app I've purchased it would be very helpful.

Comment: It could also help to mention the type of app that you're looking, in case anyone can give you a hint there.

Comment: +1 for yet another such obvious feature that simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running at least 4.3, you can use the iCloud beta to see every app you ever purchased. If you open the Updates tab of the app store, there should be a Purchased button at the top. Tapping on this will give you a list of every app you purchased on your current account. I would suggest choosing the "Not on this iPhone" tab so you don't have to look through as long of a list. Once you find the app, tap the cloud icon to download it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple primarily provides billing information via iTunes on PC and Mac. The computer that syncs the iOS device also has logs on which apps were active on certain days as part of the diagnostic logs. Without that computer, your only recourse is to ask for billing support online and leave an email / phone number. You can eventually get a human with access to your purchase records and once they are sure you are who you say you are - they might be able to pinpoint a few purchased based on time. They also may not be able to or want to help if you can't answer the questions about your account or the purchases are too numerous.

Have you thought of the receipts apple emails you after each batch of purchases? Perhaps you can identify the seller or the app name that way. The iPhone will search messages on your mail server if your mail provider allows that so even messages in the past are easily located via mobile mail on the  iPhone or a webmail interface.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason apple hides some of your purchases, to unhide them go to itunes on your computer, then Account, then Hidden Purchases.

You should then be able to download these purchases or choose to unhide them so that you can access them through the normal purchase tab.

*Note: This worked for me on Mac Mountain Lion with iTunes 11*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I don't think it is obvious for everybody which option they have to select in iTunes for this. Can you elaborate a bit and maybe add a (link to a) screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Goto updates for apps and touch the purchased